# Select radio buttons by name in Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I am trying to select radio buttons group by its name doing this:

```
Ext.select('*[name=job[sometext]]')
```

It gives the following error in firefox console:

```
Error parsing selector, parsing failed at "]"
```

I know it is because of the `[]` used in name attribute but I can't change it. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `Ext.select('*[name=job\\[sometext\\]]')`